# Time-series Analysis Over Changing Populations

Tags: regression, time-series, probability, normalization, trend

I am looking for direction concerning approaches a problem that I have with a particular dataset that I am working on.

Consider a database query that counts the number of users *[clicking links]* on a *[daily]* basis, then producing a temporal graph to represent whether the number of users clicking each link is rising or falling over time.

Then add to that the fact that the number of website users (my population) is also changing over time, and sometimes quite dramatically. On this 'naive' basis, my measurements tend to reflect changing population sizes more than they do the underlying trends that I'm attempting to observe.

Which statistical approaches (aside from simply dividing the `clicks` by `total_users`) might you recommend to help take account of this varying dataset population size so as to more clearly represent the desired trend?

Example dataset as follows:

```
+------------+--------+-------------+
|    date    | clicks | total_users |
+------------+--------+-------------+
| 01/01/2019 |     10 |         100 |
| 02/01/2019 |     15 |         150 |
| 03/01/2019 |     20 |         180 |
| 04/01/2019 |     25 |         165 |
| 05/01/2019 |    100 |         850 |
| 06/01/2019 |    150 |         450 |
| 07/01/2019 |    200 |         770 |
| 08/01/2019 |     10 |          90 |
| 09/01/2019 |      5 |          60 |
| 10/01/2019 |      1 |         110 |
+------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: I notice in your example that the number of clicks is always lower then the total number of users. Is this coincidental, or are you recording clicks only once per user? If this is the case, you could do a binomial regression with the ratio $\text{clicked}:\text{not clicked}$ as an outcome variable.